# use my data instead of 20 newsgroup for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

For the code below can you please let me know how I can use my own data set instead of the 20newsgroup data set from sklearn.

I have 100s of chat room (.txt) files already calssified as positive and negative.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
import sklearn.feature_extraction.text as ext

categories = ['sci.space']

twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',
        categories=categories,
        remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'),
        shuffle=True,
        random_state=42)

count_chars = ext.CountVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb',
        ngram_range=(3,3),
        max_features=10).fit(twenty_train['data'])
count_words = ext.CountVectorizer(analyzer='word',
        ngram_range=(3,3),
        max_features=10,
        stop_words='english').fit(twenty_train['data'])
X = count_chars.transform(twenty_train.data)

print (count_words.get_feature_names())
print ( X[1].todense())
```

Thanks for your valuable help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the call to `fetch-20newsgroups` with code to

- load your data
- preprocess it